# Import path not found in react file

Tags: reactjs

I have

```
require.config({
paths: {
    "TestLib": "../app/lib/TestLib"
}
```

in my require.config, and which import should i use in my code?
(my code file path in under 'app' folder)

eg:

```
import {TestLib} from 'lib/TestLib';
import {TestLib} from './lib/TestLib';
import {TestLib} from 'TestLib';
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You have to use

```
import {TestLib} from './lib/TestLib';
```

As you are already in `app` folder.You have to go to `lib` and then import TestLib as above.